# SQL INSERT data from 2 tables

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables, `postcodelatlng` and `branch`.

`postcodelatlng`

| postcode | lat | lng |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB10 1XG | 57.1441650 | -2.1148480 |
| AB10 6RN | 57.1378800 | -2.1214870 |
| AB10 7JB | 57.1242740 | -2.1271900 |
| AB10 5QN | 57.1427010 | -2.0932950 |
| AB10 6UL | 57.1375470 | -2.1122330 |

`branch`

| branch | postcode |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ZE2 9TL |
| 4 | BB1 7DJ |
| 9 | YO8 9DW |

I'm trying to create a new table that for every postcode in `branch`, it lists every postcode in `postcodelatlng`.

`New table`

| from | to | from_lat | from_lng | to_lat | to_lng |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ZE2 9TL | AB10 1XG | 60.4481370 | -1.1943700 | 57.1441650 | 2.1148480 |
| ZE2 9TL | AB10 6RN | 60.4481370 | -1.1943700 | 57.1378800 | -2.1214870 |
| ZE2 9TL | AB10 7JB | 60.4481370 | -1.1943700 | 57.1242740 | -2.1271900 |
| ZE2 9TL | AB10 5QN | 60.4481370 | -1.1943700 | 57.1427010 | -2.0932950 |
| ZE2 9TL | AB10 6UL | 60.4481370 | -1.1943700 | 57.1375470 | -2.1122330 |
| BB1 7DJ | AB10 1XG | 53.7490640 | -2.4843190 | 57.1441650 | 2.1148480 |
| BB1 7DJ | AB10 6RN | 53.7490640 | -2.4843190 | 57.1378800 | -2.1214870 |
| BB1 7DJ | AB10 7JB | 53.7490640 | -2.4843190 | 57.1242740 | -2.1271900 |
| BB1 7DJ | AB10 5QN | 53.7490640 | -2.4843190 | 57.1427010 | -2.0932950 |
| BB1 7DJ | AB10 6UL | 53.7490640 | -2.4843190 | 57.1375470 | -2.1122330 |
| YO8 9DW | AB10 1XG | 53.7743390 | -1.0714240 | 57.1441650 | 2.1148480 |
| YO8 9DW | AB10 6RN | 53.7743390 | -1.0714240 | 57.1378800 | -2.1214870 |
| YO8 9DW | AB10 7JB | 53.7743390 | -1.0714240 | 57.1242740 | -2.1271900 |
| YO8 9DW | AB10 5QN | 53.7743390 | -1.0714240 | 57.1427010 | -2.0932950 |
| YO8 9DW | AB10 6UL | 53.7743390 | -1.0714240 | 57.1375470 | -2.1122330 |

I've tried doing this in Python with Pandas and SQLAlchemy but I can't get my head around that so I thought it may be easier to just do it in SQL, but I'm also stuck on that!

The lat/lng data is only held in the `postcodelatlng` but this can be added manually to the `branch` table (only 42 unique postcodes there(some branches share a postcode))

I have 120 records in `branch`, 42 unique postcodes and 1778786 records on `postcodelatlng`.

Comment: *"I'm trying to create a new table that for every postcode in branch, it lists every postcode in postcodelatlng."* `CROSS JOIN`?

Comment: Where do you get the value from_lat, from_lng?

Comment: @MeysamAsadi: the `from_lat`, `from_lng` would come from the `lat` and `lng` columns in the `postcodelatlng` table for the `from` postcode.

Comment: So to_lat and to_lng?

Comment: That also is currently only stored in the postcodelatlng table but as said, there's only 42 unique values so I can add them to the branch table if needed first. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an unconditional join, the desired table was reached, but I do not know the values of from_lat and from_lng

```
insert into newtable
select b.postcode,p.postcode,"from_lat = ?","from_lng = ?",p.lat,p.lng
from branch b join postcodelatlng p on 1 = 1
```

or cross join

```
insert into newtable
select b.postcode,p.postcode,"from_lat = ?","from_lng = ?",p.lat,p.lng
from branch b cross join postcodelatlng p
```

Comment: This worked brilliantly.

I created a new temp table with ```SELECT DISTICNT postcode INTO postcode_temp FROM branch``` then joined lat/lng data to that table to first get all the branch postcode data isolated and joined to lat/lng.

Then used a cross join to insert into the new, final table.

Thank you very much for your help Meysam